# How do I create a dynamic drop down box with just Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a temperature converter with a drop down list that allows the user to select a specific temperature unit. When the unit is selected from the drop down list I want the input bar to change so that it displays the same units. Once the unit is selected the previous unit should move down to the results area.

Shows selected option and input bar

[image: Shows selected option and input bar]

Shows conversions from Fahrenheit

[image: Shows conversions from Fahrenheit]

```js
// Listen for submit
document.querySelector('#temp-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  // Hide results
  document.querySelector('#results').style.display = 'none';

  // Show loader
  document.querySelector('#loading').style.display = 'block';

  setTimeout(calculateResults, 2000);
  
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Calculate Results
function calculateResults(e){
  console.log('Calculating...');
  // UI Vars
  const fahrenheitInput = document.querySelector('#fahrenheit');
  const celsiusInput = document.querySelector('#celsius');
  const rankineInput = document.querySelector('#rankine');
  const kelvinInput = document.querySelector('#kelvin');

  function fahrenheitConversion() {
    const ftemp = parseFloat(fahrenheitInput.value);
    const ctemp = (ftemp - 32) * (5/9);
    const rtemp = ftemp + 459.67;
    const ktemp = (ftemp - 32) * (5/9) + 273.15;
    
    celsiusInput.value = ctemp.toFixed(2);
    rankineInput.value = rtemp.toFixed(2);
    kelvinInput.value = ktemp.toFixed(2);
  }

  // function celsiusConversion() {
  //   const ctemp = parseFloat(celsiusInput.value);
  //   const ftemp = (ctemp * (9/5)) + 32;
  //   const rtemp = (ctemp * (9/5)) + 491.67;
  //   const ktemp = ctemp + 273.15;
    
  //   fahrenheitInput.value = ftemp.toFixed(2);
  //   rankineInput.value = rtemp.toFixed(2);
  //   kelvinInput.value = ktemp.toFixed(2);
  // }

  // function rankineConversion() {
  //   const rtemp = parseFloat(rankineInput.value);
  //   const ctemp = (rtemp - 491.67) * (5/9);
  //   const ftemp = rtemp - 459.67;
  //   const ktemp = rtemp * (5/9);
    
  //   celsiusInput.value = ctemp.toFixed(2);
  //   fahrenheitInput.value = ftemp.toFixed(2);
  //   kelvinInput.value = ktemp.toFixed(2);
  // }

  // function kelvinConversion() {
  //   const ktemp = parseFloat(kelvinInput.value);
  //   const ctemp = ktemp - 273.15;
  //   const rtemp = ktemp * (9/5);
  //   const ftemp = (ktemp - 273.15) * (9/5) + 32;
    
  //   celsiusInput.value = ctemp.toFixed(2);
  //   rankineInput.value = rtemp.toFixed(2);
  //   fahrenheitInput.value = ftemp.toFixed(2);
  // }
  
  // Show results
  document.querySelector('#results').style.display = 'block';

  // Hide loader
  document.querySelector('#loading').style.display = 'none';

  fahrenheitInput.addEventListener('submit', fahrenheitConversion());
  // celsiusInput.addEventListener('submit', celsiusConversion());
  // rankineInput.addEventListener('submit', rankineConversion());
  // kelvinInput.addEventListener('submit', kelvinConversion());
}
```

```html
<body class="bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <div class="card card-body text-center mt-5">
          <h1 class="heading display-5 pb-3">Temperature Converter</h1>
          <form id="temp-form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Select Temperature Unit</label>
              <select name="" id="units" class="form-control">
                <option value="ftemp" class="fval">Fahrenheit</option>
                <option value="ctemp" class="cval">Celsius</option>
                <option value="rtemp" class="rval">Rankine</option>
                <option value="ktemp" class="kval">Kelvin</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group transform">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">&deg;F</span>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="fahrenheit" placeholder="Degrees Fahrenheit">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" value="Calculate" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
            </div>
          </form>
          <!-- LOADER -->
          <div id="loading">
            <img src="img/loading.gif" alt="">
          </div>
          <!-- RESULTS -->
          <div id="results" class="pt-4">
            <h5>Results</h5>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">&deg;C</span>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="celsius" placeholder="Degrees Celsius" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">&deg;R</span>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="rankine" placeholder="Degrees Rankine" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">K</span>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="kelvin" placeholder="Kelvin" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you mean when a user selects an unit from the drop-down box, the other units go to result area? If so the post title may be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly, then you want to change the °F before your input box to whatever the input in the dropdown is, so °C for Celcius when the unit is changed. If this is the case, then the code you need is really rather simple: Just an event listener to check when the unit switches, followed by a switch loop to dynamically change the label by the input box:

```
 $("#units").change(function () {
    var unit = this.find(":selected").text();
    switch (unit) {
        case "Fahrenheit":
            $(".input-group-text").text("&deg;F");
            break
        case "Celsius":
            $(".input-group-text").text("&deg;C");
            break;
        case "Rankine":
            $(".input-group-text").text("&deg;R");
            break;
        case "Kelvin":
            $(".input-group-text").text("&deg;K");
            break;
        default:
            // You Do Not Have An Empty Option, But If You Did, It Would Go Here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To change degrees by the selected unit, texts can be changed. When selecting Celsius then input group texts and input placeholder are changed in switch function. Calculating functions could be changed by selecting if you want.

```js
const units = document.querySelector('#units');

units.addEventListener('change', function(e) {  
  let selectedUnit = units.selectedIndex;
  let degree = document.querySelector('#degree');  
        
  switch(selectedUnit) {
    case 0:
    degree.innerHTML = "&deg;F";
    document.getElementById('tag1').innerHTML = "&deg;C";
    document.getElementById('tag2').innerHTML = "&deg;R";
    document.getElementById('tag3').innerHTML = "&deg;K";
    document.getElementById('fahrenheit').placeholder = "Degrees fahrenheit";        
    break;
    case 1:
    degree.innerHTML = "&deg;C";    
    document.getElementById('tag1').innerHTML = "&deg;K";
    document.getElementById('tag2').innerHTML = "&deg;R";
    document.getElementById('tag3').innerHTML = "&deg;F";
    document.getElementById('fahrenheit').placeholder = "Degrees Celsius";
    break;
    case 2:
    degree.innerHTML = "&deg;R";    
    document.getElementById('tag1').innerHTML = "&deg;C";
    document.getElementById('tag2').innerHTML = "&deg;K";
    document.getElementById('tag3').innerHTML = "&deg;F";
    document.getElementById('fahrenheit').placeholder = "Degrees Rankine";
    break;
    case 3:    
    degree.innerHTML = "&deg;K";        
    document.getElementById('tag1').innerHTML = "&deg;C"
    document.getElementById('tag2').innerHTML = "&deg;R"
    document.getElementById('tag3').innerHTML = "&deg;F";
    document.getElementById('fahrenheit').placeholder = "Kelvin";
    break;
    default:
    degree.innerHTML = "&deg;F";
    document.getElementById('fahrenheit').placeholder = "Degrees fahrenheit";
    break;
  }
  
  
});

// Listen for submit
document.querySelector('#temp-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  // Hide results
  document.querySelector('#results').style.display = 'none';

  // Show loader
  document.querySelector('#loading').style.display = 'block';

  setTimeout(calculateResults, 2000);
  
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Calculate Results
function calculateResults(e){
  console.log('Calculating...');
  // UI Vars
  const fahrenheitInput = document.querySelector('#fahrenheit');
  const celsiusInput = document.querySelector('#celsius');
  const rankineInput = document.querySelector('#rankine');
  const kelvinInput = document.querySelector('#kelvin');

  function fahrenheitConversion() {
    const ftemp = parseFloat(fahrenheitInput.value);
    const ctemp = (ftemp - 32) * (5/9);
    const rtemp = ftemp + 459.67;
    const ktemp = (ftemp - 32) * (5/9) + 273.15;
    
    celsiusInput.value = ctemp.toFixed(2);
    rankineInput.value = rtemp.toFixed(2);
    kelvinInput.value = ktemp.toFixed(2);
  }

  // function celsiusConversion() {
  //   const ctemp = parseFloat(celsiusInput.value);
  //   const ftemp = (ctemp * (9/5)) + 32;
  //   const rtemp = (ctemp * (9/5)) + 491.67;
  //   const ktemp = ctemp + 273.15;
    
  //   fahrenheitInput.value = ftemp.toFixed(2);
  //   rankineInput.value = rtemp.toFixed(2);
  //   kelvinInput.value = ktemp.toFixed(2);
  // }

  // function rankineConversion() {
  //   const rtemp = parseFloat(rankineInput.value);
  //   const ctemp = (rtemp - 491.67) * (5/9);
  //   const ftemp = rtemp - 459.67;
  //   const ktemp = rtemp * (5/9);
    
  //   celsiusInput.value = ctemp.toFixed(2);
  //   fahrenheitInput.value = ftemp.toFixed(2);
  //   kelvinInput.value = ktemp.toFixed(2);
  // }

  // function kelvinConversion() {
  //   const ktemp = parseFloat(kelvinInput.value);
  //   const ctemp = ktemp - 273.15;
  //   const rtemp = ktemp * (9/5);
  //   const ftemp = (ktemp - 273.15) * (9/5) + 32;
    
  //   celsiusInput.value = ctemp.toFixed(2);
  //   rankineInput.value = rtemp.toFixed(2);
  //   fahrenheitInput.value = ftemp.toFixed(2);
  // }
  
  // Show results
  document.querySelector('#results').style.display = 'block';

  // Hide loader
  document.querySelector('#loading').style.display = 'none';

  fahrenheitInput.addEventListener('submit', fahrenheitConversion());
  // celsiusInput.addEventListener('submit', celsiusConversion());
  // rankineInput.addEventListener('submit', rankineConversion());
  // kelvinInput.addEventListener('submit', kelvinConversion());
}
```

```html
<body class="bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <div class="card card-body text-center mt-5">
        
          <h1 class="heading display-5 pb-3">Temperature Converter</h1>
          
          <form id="temp-form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Select Temperature Unit</label>
              <select name="" id="units" class="form-control">
                <option value="ftemp" class="fval">Fahrenheit</option>
                <option value="ctemp" class="cval">Celsius</option>
                <option value="rtemp" class="rval">Rankine</option>
                <option value="ktemp" class="kval">Kelvin</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group transform">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id='degree'>&deg;F</span>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="fahrenheit" placeholder="Degrees Fahrenheit">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" value="Calculate" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
            </div>
          </form>
          
          <!-- LOADER -->
          <div id="loading">
            <img src="img/loading.gif" alt="">
          </div>
          <!-- RESULTS -->
          <div id="results" class="pt-4">
            <h5>Results</h5>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="tag1">&deg;C</span>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="celsius" placeholder="Degrees Celsius" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="tag2">&deg;R</span>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="rankine" placeholder="Degrees Rankine" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend" >
                <span class="input-group-text" id="tag3">K</span>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="kelvin" placeholder="Kelvin" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! How would I change change my calculating functions to fit the selected unit?

Comment: @Zanto You're welcome! Putting addEventListener and removeEventListener into the switch function will be helpful! These switch function looks messy but long codes can be shorten with functions too.